# Error when trying to save image in PostgreSQL 9.6.13 - syntax error at or near “\”, but finely store PostgreSQL 8.2.23

Tags: java, postgresql, bytea

I have problem to store image in postgresql **9.6.13** version in my table column data type `bytea` format, but this data type `bytea` finely run on postgresql **8.2.23** version.

Comment: Please show some code, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Read all the release notes between PostgreSQL 8.2.23 and 9.6.13 and find out what changed.

Comment: 8.3 has been unsupported for a long time. Why are you using such an outdated version?

Comment: It most probably has to do with the change in [bytea output encoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-BYTEA-OUTPUT)  introduced in 9.4

Answer (score -1):

You can replace the "path separator" in the path, you can replace with the separator of system. For example in java to use java.io.File.separator.